# Отправка post запроса в form data

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

я делаю post запрос на сервер.

```
HEADERS= {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36'
}
s = requests.Session()
s.get("https://www.heroeswm.ru")
data = {'LOGIN_redirect': '1', 'login': login, 'pass': password, 'pliv': 15248}
r = s.post("https://www.heroeswm.ru/login.php", data=data, headers=HEADERS)
r.encoding = 'windows-1251'
data1 = {'code': 'pvqddq','id': 50,'id2':50,'idr': '897bebdecc7c367282e05cc929ea2808','num': 
2878,'id3': '26fce65b547682c0bd867135fe992c92'}
e = requests.post('https://www.heroeswm.ru/object-info.php?id=50', data = data1,headers = HEADERS)
```

По идеи, он должен поле 'code' ввести в текстовое поле.
Как я понял, сайт принимает и другие параметры такие как: id,id2,idr,num,id3
Я их вроде тоже передаю, но они постоянно меняются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Данные, которые ожидает от меня увидеть сайт.

1. Вопрос, как я могу эти поля получить досрочно, т.е не зная их
2. И в правильном ли направлении я двигаюсь, потому что после запуска, он только логинится и все, и не вводит в поле капчу, и не нажимает на кнопку

Answer (score 0):

```
r = s.post("https://www.heroeswm.ru/login.php", data=data, headers=HEADERS)
```

Скорее всего эти переменные генерируются в результате отправки запроса на "логин" и хранятся либо в сессии, либо как cookie.

Comment: Хорошо, а я могу как то предугадать их? Какие будут эти переменные, чтобы я мог их post запросе указать

Comment: Вы получаете эти данные в ответ на запрос о логине. Зачем Вам их предугадывать?

Comment: С авторизацией у меня все ок, но далее, когда он должен перейти по след.ссылке, ввести в текстовое поле капчу, он этого не делает. Т.е это тот запрос где я должен указать 'code',id,id2 ...., и я вот не пойму, у меня правильно запрос составлен, я просто не уверен, что я именно в это текстовое поле передаю параметры